# Jest :No test found

Tags: javascript, jestjs, integration-testing

I am trying to have some integration tests on my project using `npm test` and my directory is like this:

Main_directory==>tests==>integration==>auth.test.js and bar.test.js

On my package.json, I've got this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose"
  },
```

when I execute the code `npm test` , I run into this mind-boggling error on terminal:

```
No tests found

In G:\main_directory
  35 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 5 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 35 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

Do you have any idea on how to bring everything back to normal and run some smooth integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

You are matching for the folder `__tests__` but you said that your tests are in the `test` folder. So either change the folder name where the tests are to `__test__` or change the name in your jest config.

Comment: It simply doesn't change anything if I modify the folder name .Just wondering how I could change the name in jest config. Should it take place in jest/jest-config/package.json?

Comment: There are many ways to configure jest. Check out their [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration). You probably want to modify `testMatch`

Comment: In Jest-config/build/valid.config.js , there's this `testMatch` code as following:
`testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)']`

I'm afraid I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: add `"jest": {
    "testMatch": ['**/tests/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)']
  }` to your package.json as stated in the documencation I just linked

Comment: I added `add "jest": { "testMatch": ['**/tests/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)'] }` to the main package and no luck yet.